# Number Theory Primitive Roots Confusion

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The following theorem is in my lecture notes:

If p is a prime number, then there exist φ(p-1) distinct primitive roots modulo p.

I am struggling to make sense of this.

φ(m) is the number of integers coprime to m, less than or equal to m and greater than or equal to 1.

So, for example φ(11)= the number of integers in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}=10

But according to this theorem, the number of distinct primitive roots modulo 11 is φ(10)= the size of {1,3,7,9} = 4.

I know I have completely misunderstood some of the concepts here but cant quite figure out where I have gone wrong.

I would appreciate is somebody could help clear up the confusion

Comment: Perhaps you don't know what a primitive root is.

Comment: You have had a couple of answers. Have you found them helpful? Do you still have a question?

Answer (score 3):

Actually your set $\{1,3,7,9\}$ is correct. The interpretation is, first get one primitive root, say $2$; then 
take the powers of $2$ modulo $11$, corresponding to the numbers as  indices.
So we get $2^1=2; 2^3=8; 2^7=128\equiv7; 2^9=512\equiv6 $, we get the set $\{2,6,7,8\}$ mentioned by gammatester. (Actually this set will be the same even if we started with different primitive root, for example, $6^1, 6^3, 6^7, 6^9$ will lead to the same set when taken modulo $11$.)

Answer (score 0):

The primitive roots are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^{*},$ which are $\{2,6,7,8\}.$ Check the $x$ from this set to give $x^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ and lower powers are $\not \equiv 1,$ e.g. $2^{10}=1024\equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ and 
$2^{5}=32\equiv 10 \pmod {11}.\;$

Your set $\{1,3,7,5\}$ is wrong because e.g. $3^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}.$